# How to handle invalid ID in react-router route in a redux app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have the route `/messages/:id` that renders a message. However if `id` is pointing to a non-existing message, where and how should that be handled? My component is bound to the message using redux:

```
function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
  return {
    message: state.messages[ownProps.params.id]
  }
}
```

Then `message` will be `undefined` in case no such message exist and the component must handle that, and render something different.
However, this seems to bloat the component and I think maybe this should be handled in the router? If there is no such message, it should not allow the route to be called.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I too am interested in this too and I have a solution, though not the most elegant one. Hopefully this will help though.

```
import NotFound from './NotFound'
import Message from './Message'
import {asyncGetMessage} from './api'

const onEnter = ({params, location}, replaceState, callback) => {
  asyncGetMessage(params.messageId)
    .then((isFound) => {
      location.isFound = isFound
      callback()
    })
}

const getComponent = (Component) => {
  return (location, callback) => {
    callback(null, (state) => {
      if (location.isFound) {
        state.route.status = 200
        return <Component {...state} />
      } else {
        state.route.status = 404
        return <NotFound {...state} />
      }
    })
  }
}

const routes = (
  <Route path='messages'>
    <Route path=':messageId' getComponent={getComponent(Message)} onEnter={onEnter} />
  </Route>
)
```

What is happening here is the `onEnter` method is called initially and waits for the callback. The `onEnter` calls the `asyncGetMessage` promise and sets the `isFound` property on the `location` to `true` or `false`.

Then `getComponent` is called, I used a factory to provide the `Message` component as `Component`. It needs to return a callback, and within the callback, `error` and a function with `state` as the first argument. From there it checks the `isFound` property on `location` and returns either the `Component` setup in the factory or the `NotFound` component.

I am also setting the the route `status` to 404 so the server can provide the correct http code when it is rendering the first page load.

Unfortunately the signature of `getComponent` doesn't receive state, otherwise it would be possible to do it all there instead of using `onEnter` too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmmm interesting approach, Marc. Although it would also mean that the navigation might have a slight delay, depending on how long the async call takes.
Thinking about it, maybe its better to display the the component and a progress bar during the update and when there is no such ID then it displays/routes to an error page (possibly with a retry handler).

Comment: @philk It depends on your use-case, blocking the router is useful if you want your pages crawled while leaving out pages that don't exist (hence offering a 404). This could be improved by serving up different functionality for server and browser. But as I implied, this is not a perfect solution, it's more of a thought experiment.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but my final thoughts on this are, that it is not the concern of the router or a getComponent Wrapper, but only the concern of the Component itself to handle it's own (faulty) state.

When your Component is able to be mounted in an erroneous state, like message = undefined, then your Component should react according to the erroneous state.

Preventing your Component from the erroneous state would be an alternative too, but this bloats your code anyways and the Component would still not be able to handle it's error state.

Comment: Agreed.  This type of situation is best handled by the server/backend, rather than by the client.